# Adding old column to replacement table

Tags: mysql

I just added new table in my database to track image views.. like so

```
viewcount 
DATE 
IMAGE_ID 
NUMVIEWS
```

I don't know how in the world to add the old views that I tracked before, which was just a column Views in the image table like so..

```
imageTable
IMAGE_ID 
NUMVIEWS  // 2654 or whatever
```

I want to add them all as an arbitrary date.
ex: 12/21/2012
seems so complicated.. maybe should just reset all views and go on with the new table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `INSERT` them from the old table?

```
INSERT INTO viewcount (date, image_id, numviews)
SELECT '2012-12-21' AS date, image_id, numviews FROM imageTable
```

If you want to update the actual `numviews` you can try:

```
UPDATE viewcount 
LEFT JOIN imageTable ON imageTable.image_id = viewcount.image_id
SET viewcount.numviews = viewcount.numviews + imageTable.numviews
```

Be aware that this will update records for *any* date.